# Always count the opportunity every month via trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

How can I display and refresh the field for new opportunities every month? This is the code

```
trigger CountOpp on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {


    List<Franchise_Agent__c> agents = [SELECT Id, Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c,
        (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r WHERE StageName='Closed Won') 
        FROM Franchise_Agent__c 
        WHERE Id IN (SELECT Franchise_Agent__c FROM Opportunity Where ID in :Trigger.new)];

    List<Franchise_Agent__c> agentsToUpdate = new List<Franchise_Agent__c>();

    for(Franchise_Agent__c a : agents ){
        Integer closedWon = a.Opportunities__r.size();
        if(a.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c != closedWon)
        {
            a.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c = closedWon;
            agentsToUpdate.add(a);
        }   
    }

    if(agentsToUpdate.size() > 0)
        update agentsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Do you need something like 'Field_Avg_per_Month = Number_Of_Closed_Won_Opps / 12' ?

Comment: No, what i need is the closed won for the current month.. if i have closed won 3 opportunity in september, by october 1, the number of closed won will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will return what you are looking for:

```
Integer count = [SELECT COUNT() 
                 FROM Opportunity 
                 WHERE CloseDate = THIS_MONTH 
                 AND StageName = 'Closed Won'
                 AND Franchise_Agent__c = :agentId];

System.debug(count);
```